# Como fazer animação de uma view através de arquivo XML?

Tags: android

Como eu faço para fazer animação em um imageview com o arquivo de animação em XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa começar vendo isto: [View Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

Veja só um exemplo de como podemos fazer um `Blink Animation`. Que é o tipo de animação que fica **piscando** a **view**.

> blink.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<alpha
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Todas essas **tags** (**duration**, **fromAlpha**, **interporlator**, ...) são explicadas no link que mandei para você.

Mas, adiantando, as tags principais para esse tipo de animação, são essas: **duration**, **fromAlpha**, **toAlpha**.

- **Duration**: define o tempo em que a animação vai atualizar, ou seja, quanto maior, mais lento o efeito vai ser realizado.
- **fromAlpha**: é responsável por deixar a view invisível.
- **toAlpha**: ele vai clarear a view.

Para aplicar a animação em qualquer view, faça isso:

```
yourImageView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.blink)).
```

Para pausar a animação em andamento, faça isso:

```
yourImageView.clearAnimation();
```

Você pode encontrar mais exemplos de animações em: **[API Demos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchboarder.android.api.demos&hl=pt-br)**